# What is a valid character in an identifier called?

Tags: parsing, ascii, lexical-analysis

Identifiers typically consist of underscores, digits; and uppercase and lowercase characters where the first character is not a digit. When writing lexers, it is common to have helper functions such as `is_digit` or `is_alnum`. If one were to implement such a function to scan a character used in an identifier, what would it be called? Clearly, `is_identifier` is wrong as that would be the entire token that the lexer scans and not the individual character. I suppose `is_alnum_or_underscore` would be accurate though quite verbose. For something as common as this, I feel like there should be a single word for it.

Comment: I think `is_alnum_or_underscore` would be inappropriate, because it's coupling to an implementation detail (what if you decide you want to allow dollar signs, or question marks? What about numbers, which you may want to disallow from the start of an identifier). I took a quick peak at the language I'm most familiar with, Swift, and in their grammar documentation, they describe an identifier as starting with an "identifier head" followed by "identifier characters" https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html

Comment: Some other points of comparison: [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8), [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#643-identifiers), [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html)

Comment: This definitely gives me some ideas. Thank you very much for the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode Annex 31 (*Unicode Identifier and Pattern Syntax*, [UAX31](https://unicode.org/reports/tr31/)) defines a framework for the definition of the lexical syntax of identifiers, which is probably as close as we're going to come to a standard terminology. UAX31 is used (by reference) by Python and Rust, and has been approved for C++23. So I guess it's pretty well mainstream.

UAX31 defines three sets of identifier characters, which it calls *Start*, *Continue* and *Medial*. All *Start* characters are also *Continue* characters; no *Medial* character is a *Continue* character.

That leads to the simple regular expression (**UAX31-D1** *Default Identifier Syntax*):

```
<Identifier> := <Start> <Continue>* (<Medial> <Continue>+)*
```

A programming language which claims conformance with UAX31 does not need to accept the exact membership of each of these sets, but it must explicitly spell out the deviations in what's called a "profile". (There are seven other requirements, which are not relevant to this question. See the document if you want to fall down a very deep rabbit hole.)

That can be simplified even more, since neither UAX31 nor (as far as I know) the profile for any major language places any characters in *Medial*. So you can go with the flow and just define two categories: *identifier-start* and *identifier-continue*, where the first one is a subset of the second one.

You'll see that in a number of grammar documents:

**[Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)**

```
identifier   ::=  xid_start xid_continue*
```

[**Rust**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/identifiers.html)

```
IDENTIFIER_OR_KEYWORD : XID_Start XID_Continue*
                      | _ XID_Continue+
```

[**C++**](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name)

```
identifier:
        identifier-start
        identifier identifier-continue
```

So that's what I'd suggest. But there are many other possibilities:

[**Swift**](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html)

Calls the sets *identifier-head* and *identifier-characters*

[**Java**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-3.html#jls-Identifier)

Calls them *JavaLetter* and *JavaLetterOrDigit*

**C**

Defines *identifier-nondigit* and *identifier-digit*; Continue would be the union of the two sets.